# C++ cache visibility

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm going through stackoverflow and other doc regarding C++ multithreading and it may have answered in some other discussion but I can't seem to find a satisfying answer about how C++ ensure values are not just cached and can be instructed to be written to the main memory so that other threads can read it. Say we have the following:

```
int x; 
x = 15;
```

This 15 could be stored in CPU cache and be written out in memory later on. So even after this code is executed, other threads accessing x could be reading some old values.

Let's say we have:

```
atomic<int> x;
x.store(15);
```

If I understand correctly, this ONLY ensures "some" (depending on our memory_order flag) ordering regarding how compiler can't reorder other load/store operations on x. It does NOT talk about whether this 15 is stored in cache or in main memory or what not.. Other threads loading this x could still be reading a stale value (please correct me if I'm wrong)

So how do we achieve that once the instruction of storing 15 is executed, it's written into the main memory (or at least flagged somehow in other CPU cache) such that some subsequent read knows to get the new value?

(Java volatile keyword does this trick)

Thanks,

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/C-Concurrency-Action-Practical-Multithreading/dp/1933988770

Comment: `std::atomic` ensures that reading from and writing to it is a thread-safe operation. It doesn't guarantee that it will be written to main memory or not - that's implementation defined. Though on modern X86 CPUs the cache line will likely be simply locked during the read or write.